# What's the difference between array adapter & android.entries in spinner?

Tags: android

What difference does it make, if I assign some items using an ArrayAdapter or using android:entries?
Which drawbacks will I face, related to a Spinner functionality?

Adding elements using android:entries

```
<Spinner
            android:id="@+id/edu"
            android:layout_width="211dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:entries="@array/education"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />"
```

Adding the items using an ArrayAdapter:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.edu));
                        arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        education_2.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. You've assigned two different arrays

Comment: Can not use dynamic array

Answer (score 1):

`android:entries` is a static string XML list. You cannot update the Spinner content via Java code. Similarly, (maybe I forget the property, but) in the Java code you are able to use a different layout than `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`

If that's not required for your application, there's no drawback as the XML you have gets roughly translated into the same Java code.

Comment: can you help me how to make first item disabled so that it can be used only to show for to get which data spinner is to be used and that item cannot be selected?

Comment: All elements are always selectable. You only use an if statement to check the position/value  when extracting data. If you have an additional question, though,  feel free to create a new post

Answer (score 0):

If you're curious how an XML attribute is used, the Android source code is your friend. You can see that `Spinner` extends `AbsSpinner` and that has a constructor defined like this:

```
public AbsSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    initAbsSpinner();

    final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs, R.styleable.AbsSpinner, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);

    final CharSequence[] entries = a.getTextArray(R.styleable.AbsSpinner_entries);
    if (entries != null) {
        final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(
                context, R.layout.simple_spinner_item, entries);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    a.recycle();
}
```

As you can see, the code checks if the `entries` attribute is set and, if it is, creates a default `ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>`to display the given set of strings.

So, to answer your questions:

> What difference it makes if I assign items using array adapter or using in build android:entries ?

If you just need to show a list of strings, there's really no difference. The `entries` attribute is a *convenience* if you simply need to display a list of strings in a default spinner view without additional customization.

> What drawback I will face related to functionality of spinner?

There's no difference in *functionality* - it's still a spinner of strings. But you cannot customize the type of item or style of the views in the spinner. So if you need a different layout or more customization in how your items are displayed, you would write the extra code to create and set your own adapter.

Hope that helps!